# Что нужно задать при запуске dotnet run, чтобы сработало #if TRACE?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

```cs
#if TRACE
```

Как задать `TRACE`, чтобы условие выполнилось?

Comment: так то это директивы препроцессора, то есть отвечают за условную компиляцию и доступны только при компиляции выбирая какой код будет в итоге скомпилирован. А при выполнении ничего такого нет.

Comment: Символы можно определить в файле с кодом: [Defining symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#defining-symbols), можно задать их в файле настроек проекта: [DefineConstants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#defineconstants), можно передать опции компилятору: [How to: Compile Conditionally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-compile-conditionally-with-trace-and-debug).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43743808/5045688 - вот ещё гляньте